# How to update zip file with XML content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, xml, zip

### Overview

I am using JSZip which allows you to create and update zip files using JavaScript. I would like to update some of the contents of the zip file with other files. However the examples in the documentation only show how to use `strings`.

In my situation I have an XML file and I want to overwrite another XML file within the Zip file. According to the documentation the file() method supports multiple types:

```
file(name, data [,options])
```

`String/ArrayBuffer/Uint8Array/Buffer/Blob/Promise/Nodejs stream`

### Question

I have access to my zip file and my XML file is local as it will be built pro-grammatically. How can I go about using this method to overwrite files with XML files. I also expect the need to overwrite images as well but I also didn't see examples of this either.

Documentation - https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

If I do an import of the XML:

```
import testXML from '../testXML';
```

This will not work as when I console log this, I get:
`static/media/testXML.dd632dc5.xml`

Note: I am using React for the frontend if this matters.